# Open cv and Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to load a video frame to tkinter label. I tried running following method. my web cam turns on but feed does not loads on the label. Is there a time interval limit I should use of ?

```
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.updateCamera()


def updateCamera(self):
    # Get a frame from the video source

    ret, frame = self.cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800,600))
    frame = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
    frame = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame)
    self.camraLabel.configure(image=frame)
    print("Here")
    self.camraLabel.after(1000,self.updateCamera)
```

if I comment out `self.camraLabel.after(1000,self.updateCamera)` a still image appears on the label. Can't think of what I have done wrong.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the image, otherwise it will be garbaged.  Try adding `self.camraLabel.frame = frame` after `.configure(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You created a recursive function that will never end. This is bad, can you see how the function will never exit? It also prevents the label from updating, so you never see an image. Instead you should use a time based loop, like for example the following:

```
    import time
    import cv2

    # store current time
    curr_time = time.time()
    # get camera 
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def updateCamera(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800,600))
        frame = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
        frame = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame)
        self.camraLabel.configure(image=frame)
        print("Here")

    # loop forever
    while True:
            # check if the frame needs to be updated
            if time.time()-curr_time > 1:
                    # if more then a second has passed,
                    # get a new frame and update curr_time
                    self.updateCamera()
                    curr_time = time.time()

            # do other stuf
```

*Disclaimer: untested code*